# "a consistent representation" VS. "a representation close to reality"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrase-meaning

Despite the accurate descriptions in the pastoral visits, in the canvas of **** the church appears to be located more southerly; this is may be due to the artist's will, who in such way would seem not to care about giving to it a **consistent representation** / **representation close to reality**.

Which would you use?

Comment: Would "An accurate representation" suit your intended meaning? If so, I'd prefer it to either of those options.

Comment: Despite the accurate descriptions in the pastoral visits, **** appears to use artistic licence in their painting, moving the position of the church further south.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the accurate descriptions in the pastoral visits, in the canvas of **** the church appears to be located more southerly; this is may be due to the artist's will, who in such way would seem not to care about giving to it a **factual** representation